# Updating registry cache message during jspm package installation

Tags: package, jspm

When I run **jspm install Aurelia-framework** at the command prompt, I see a message **Updating Registry Cache...**.

Is the **jspm** updating the Windows Operating System registry or **package.json** file in the project or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that jspm-cli fetches https://github.com/jspm/registry which provides overrides and short names for popular packages. See the source code to understand what's happening when jspm updates the registry cache: https://github.com/jspm/registry-endpoint/blob/master/registry.js#L182